# Notepad++ and MiKTeX -- CMD not recognizing commands/exes

Tags: miktex, editors, paths

Currently, I can't get a batch file/run command combo to compile my .tex files into PDFs -- it throws an error at multiple lines, which I will mark in the code with an '*' before them. The only solution I found for this was to change the path file to add the MiKTeX directory -- which I have done, and the problem persists. I haven't been able to find any other fixes.

First, the run command:

```
"C:\Users\Matthew\Desktop\latex.bat" "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" "$(NAME_PART)"
```

Then, the .bat itself

```
%~d1
cd %1

*call:cleanup

*pdflatex %2
*bibtex  %2
*pdflatex %2
*pdflatex %2

*call:cleanup

START "" "C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" %2 -reuse-instance

del *.dvi
del *.aux
del *.bbl
del *.blg
del *.brf
del *.out
goto:eof
```

All of the code was lifted from [this webpage](http://nimal.info/blog/2010/latex-on-windows-with-miktex-and-notepad/).

The only functioning parts as best I can tell are the run command itself, the launching of the PDF program (and it attempting to open a file that doesn't exist, since MiKTeX isn't working), and the deletion of the log files at the very end. PDFLatex on its own can be called through the command prompt, but for some reason trying to put it in the batch file doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The Question is a cut down version of the linked source file **it will not work correctly** since there is no :cleanup line thus call:cleanup will fail until the default del(s) at the end.

"The system cannot find the batch label specified - cleanup"

Whilst the batch file does appear to run per the description the SumatraPDF will also understandably fail since the command is again wrong without the.pdf

what is odd is that from the description even if those corrections were made it should run PDFLATEX etc. but without a clue as to the output errors no one can tell why not.

To catch the errors put a pause on a separate line after the one that has start SumatraPDF.

**In case the linked source is removed here is a corrected version per my comments above.** Note the authors pre-conditions 
A tex bin (MiKTeX or TeX Live must be on path
This batch file is called with  two separate quoted arguments
 A) the quoted full path to the tex file e.g.  "d:\my docs"
 B) the quoted filename without extension  e.g. "my tex file"
It may be run from a command prompt or from an editor

It can even be modified to be called from the PDF within SumatraPDF such that running from the PDF viewer it could recompile any simple changes made in bog standard MSnotePad or Wordpad/write (who needs an IDE editor :-)

```
%~d1
cd %1
:: the following line will delete all files listed below prior to a new run and again as it opens the pdf so do NOT list the synctex files
call:cleanup
:: the following calls do not include common requirements such as -synctex=1 etc. (compare with your normal workflow)
pdflatex %2
bibtex  %2
pdflatex %2
pdflatex %2

"C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" %2.pdf  

:cleanup
del *.dvi
del *.aux
del *.bbl
del *.blg
del *.brf
del *.out
:: the following eof is needed once to return to the initial call above then will be ignored on final run
goto:eof
```